# Find out windows version from non-privileged user command line

Tags: windows, cmd

I need a way to find out what version of windows I'm running in using simple command line tools (no powershell).  I need it to work from a non-privileged user, and I need to be able to parse out the difference between Windows XP, Vista, server 2008, and 7.  I'm currently using:
`wmic os get Caption` but that fails when the user doesn't have permissions to run wmic.

**Update:**
To clarify, I need this command to not break with different service pack levels, etc. which probably rules out parsing a specific version number.  Also if you look at [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of windows versions, you'll see that the numbers reported on Windows 7 and server 2008 r2 are the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved this problem by parsing the output of:

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"
```

Comment: In addition to `ProductName`, there are other useful values in that registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, notably `CurrentVersion` (e.g. =`6.3`) and `CurrentBuild` (e.g. =`9600`).

Answer (score 12):

systeminfo command shows everything about the os version including service pack number and the edition you are using.

```
C:\>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
```

Reference: [Find Windows version from command prompt](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/)

Comment: This take too long to run and is not cleanly parsable from another program because it creates and then deletes quite a bit of text.

Comment: This only works on English versions of Windows.  Strings like "OS Name" may be localized.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ver`. I'm on a school computer with a non-privileged command prompt, and it gives me `Microsft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`. I'm sure you'd be able to sort out Vista and XP from the number you get.

Answer (score 4):

`cmd` displays the Windows version when started:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Joey>_
```

This is also a similar line as the one `ver` spits out, indeed.

One option then might be

```
echo exit|cmd|findstr Windows
```

another

```
cmd /c ver
```

depending on whether you have a pipeline or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not CMDEXTVERSION 2 (
  echo Error: This batch requires Command Extensions version 2 or higher
  exit /b 1
)

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=4 delims=] " %%I IN (`ver`) DO for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%J IN ("%%I") do set WindowsVersion=%%J.%%K
if "%WindowsVersion%" LSS "6.1" (
  echo Error: This batch requires Windows 7 SP1 or higher
  exit /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SysInternals and install onto your C:\ directory.  After that you can then go to a command prompt and use the command PSINFO.

It is great because it lets me query any PC on the network (that I have access to).  At the command prompt you type:  PSINFO \exactnameofcomputer

(PSINFO whack whack exactnameofcomputer)

Then hit enter.  It will take a moment or two to report back, depending on where that computer is located at.