# Puppet Check Windows Version

Tags: windows, puppet

In puppet how could I check what specific windows version an agent is running on? According to [the puppet docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/writing.html#notable-windows-facts) all three identifying facts only specify that the node is running windows, not if it is running windows server 2003, 2008, or 2012.

Is there a way to do this without checking using registry/command line to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operatingsystemrelease` fact should work for your case. Running in my pc:

```
C:\Projects>facter operatingsystemrelease
6.1.7601
```

I get `6.1.7601`, that corresponds to Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Ah so I am going to have to go based on the kernel version. Was hoping there was a more pretty to look at solution, but I guess I could just make it pretty myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I asked a version of this same questions myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389312/find-out-windows-version-from-non-privileged-user-command-line).

The simple answer is parse the output of:

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"
```