# Overview CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION values for Windows

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm not a Windows user but work on supporting our C++ software also for Windows.

I would like to know the Windows version (7, 10, 11).

cmake gives for the system I have remote terminal access to and which shall be Windows 11 with current updates (Oct 2023)
the values

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Windows"
CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION="10.0.22621"
CCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR="AMD64"
```

Is there a list on how to decode Windows 10 and 11 from CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION?

Comment: CMake just extracts Windows system version by using one of these commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778858/how-to-get-windows-version-from-command-prompt-or-from-powershell. So, interpretation of the version is not a CMake-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a list on how to decode Windows 10 and 11 from CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION?

The value `22621` in `10.0.22621` corresponds to the Windows 11 build version for the Windows 11 version `23H2`.  See [Windows 11 Release Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information).

Microsoft also provides build versions for Windows 10.  See [Windows 10 Release Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information).

There are also some secondary sources of this info.  You can check Wikipedia's articles on [Windows 11 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11_version_history) and [Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history).